# How important is the procedure to service a car every 6 months

Tags: service

Recently I bought a car. The recommendation is to do the service every 12,000 kms or 6 months.

I'm using the car for about 400 kms per month. I'm far from the next service. But I received a call from the retailer telling me that I have to do the service, otherwise, I'll lose the guarantee of the car. (this isn't the 2 years guarantee) this is an extended guarantee.

I was thinking about the real necessity to do the service if the car isn't used enough. I use the car every week but just a few kilometers, in my idea this will make the fluids to move and aren't enough to desgaste the parts.

Answer (score 2):

If you bought the car new, I would highly recommend following the service schedule while you are still under warranty.  Furthermore, you will likely void the warranty if you don't have the services performed at the specified intervals.

If the services are free, you should definitely do them, they will extend the life of your vehicle at no cost to you. If you have to pay for the service, it's basically like an insurance policy. If you pay for the service now, and then goes wrong under warranty you'll be covered. If you skip the service and something goes wrong, your warranty will be void and you'll have to pay to have it fixed.